# Mutation threshold in PITest: is there a way to set a default average threshold globally across multiple projects or modules?

Tags: java, maven, junit, mutation, pitest

I now have set mutation configuration on the main project pom and I want it to be calculated as an average instead of each module separately.
Is there a way to do that?

```
<mutationThreshold>80</mutationThreshold>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have not found a way to calculate the average mutation but the threshold can be set separately in each module (in the pom.xml file) therefore bypassing the main pom.xml mentioned mutation threshold value.